# How to get a match of results from MySQL database that are between characters?

Tags: mysql, between

Using MySQL how can I query for all records that start with a certain letter ranging from one letter to another? For example I want to find all entries that have the first letter between a-f.

Matches:
Albert
Donald
Frank

Non Matches:
Sarah
Reba
Thomas

With numbers I can use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= int AND id <= int
```

Or use the between statement. How can I do that using letters using the first letter of each word in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a range here.  To cover `a` through and including `f`, regardless of case, we can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (name >= 'a' AND name < 'g') OR (name >= 'A' AND name < 'G');
```

### Demo

Note that this approach leaves open the possibility of MySQL being able to use an index which might exist on the `name` column.

As @John commented below, if you are not using a collation which is case sensitive, then we can simplify the above query to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE name >= 'a' AND name < 'g';
```

Comment: Unless you specify binary, I believe mysql is not case sensitive by default. Could be wrong.

Comment: @John I think you're right, but anyway my answer might be useful for someone who is using a binary collation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression for this. Read more here: [REGEX_LIKE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html). The query you need will be like this:

**MySQL 8.0**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    <table_name>
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(<column_name>, '^[a-f]');
```

**MySQL < 8.0**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    <table_name>
WHERE
    <column_name> REGEXP '^[a-f]';
```

This will match all register with  starting with [a to f] range letters.